# How to pass two "names" to access in the server from one input tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to access the name in my server side. But, I also need chartSheetButton, so I wonder how to acccess both  in the server side?

Here, I have an input tag, inside of a form.

I tried with id, but didn't work.

```
const formSheet = document.createElement('form');formSheet.setAttribute('method',"POST"); 
const chartSheet = document.createElement('input');
chartSheet.setAttribute('type','submit');
chartSheet.setAttribute('name','chartSheetButton');
chartSheet.setAttribute('id','peter');
chartSheet.setAttribute('value','Chart Sheet');
formSheet.append(chartSheet);
```

Comment: `I tried with id, but didn't work`. Could you please post the code?

Comment: it is posted already

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.chartSheetButton);
})
```

Dont forget to add the "action" attribute to your form.